# GLSL Fragment Shader Fails to Compile with no message

Tags: go, opengl, glsl, go-gl

I'm using the [go-gl](https://github.com/go-gl) bindings for OpenGl.

I've defined the source for two shaders as follows:

```go
const vertexShaderSource = `#version 460 compatibility
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}` + "\x00"
const fragmentShaderSource = `#version 460 compatibility
out vec4 FragColor;
void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(0.5f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
}` + "\x00"
```

The vertex shader gets created and compiled without issue.

Here's code that creates and compiles the fragment shader:

```go
fragmentShader := gl.CreateShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
fragmentShaderSourceC := gl.Str(fragmentShaderSource)
gl.ShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSourceC, nil)
gl.GetShaderiv(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS, &success)
if success != gl.TRUE {
    var length int32
    infoLogC := [LOGSIZE]uint8{}
    gl.GetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, LOGSIZE, &length, &infoLogC[0])
    infoLog := gl.GoStr(&infoLogC[0])
    fmt.Printf("Got failure from fragment shader: %s\n", infoLog)
    fmt.Printf("gl version: %s\n", gl.GoStr(gl.GetString(gl.VERSION)))
    fmt.Printf("gl vendor: %s\n", gl.GoStr(gl.GetString(gl.VENDOR)))
    return
}
```

Which outputs the following (frustratingly, no info log message):

```
Got failure from fragment shader: 
gl version: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1
gl vendor: Intel
```

I've tried toggling between version `core`/`compatibility`, changing the name of `FragColor`, and different values in `vec4`.

I've also tried commenting out the `if` block and continuing on to create the program anyway. The block that checks the program outputs an error, which is expected since the shader didn't compile: `error: linking with uncompiled/unspecialized shader`

Any feedback on how to get the fragment shader to compile?

Comment: 1) Does go automatically insert linebreaks into strings? If not, then your shaders are just one single line. 2) Do you get a valid error message when you add a syntax error to the vertex shader? For example, remove the ;?

Comment: 1) Yes, the strings do have linebreaks.

2) I inserted the line `foo bar` into the source code with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [`glShaderSource()`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glShaderSource.xhtml) only sets the source code for the shader. It **does not** compile. You need to separately call [`glCompileShader()`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCompileShader.xhtml) after.

```c
gl.ShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSourceC, nil)
gl.CompileShader(fragmentShader)
```

The reason [`gl.GetShaderiv()`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) with `gl.COMPILE_STATUS` results in `success` being `gl.FALSE`. Is because `gl.COMPILE_STATUS` only results in `gl.TRUE` if the last compilation was successful. However, since you never called `gl.CompileShader()`, then there was no previous successful compilation, thereby you receive `gl.FALSE`. Additionally, since there also hasn't been any error so far, then the info log is also empty.